# Angular Material icons not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I've installed Material for angular,

I've imported on my app module MatIconModule (with `import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';`)

I've added it under my ngmodule imports with:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
//...
MatIconModule, 
//...
```

I've imported all stylesheets

And I've also imported it in my app component that is actually (trying to) using them (with another `import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';` line at the beginning of it).

But material icons still not appear.

For example, with this line:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

I'm expecting something like this:

[image: expected]

But i get this:

[image: actual]

Got any suggestion?

Comment: The font might be missing. or it is loaded later.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani how can I check this?

Comment: after performing the solutions from below , you should clear browser cache . it worked for me .

Comment: npm i material-icons --legacy-peer-deps then : @import "~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
works For erevryone

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Add CSS stylesheet for Material Icons!

Add the following to your index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Refer - https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7948

Comment: This answer worked for me but I was also able to add this line to the styles.css and it worked.

```@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';```

Comment: You can also add:
`@import "~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";`
to your styles.css

Comment: @PooshonBanerjee material-icons is a separate project not maintained by the Angular Material team.

Comment: Often not enough. What people forget is:
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MatIconModule,
        ................
       ],

Comment: To complement your answer, this font could be installed using npm at this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons

Then is necessary to import css: @import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
or <link href="/path/to/material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 94):

For Angular 6+:

1. npm install this: `npm install material-design-icons`
2. add the styles to angular.json:

   ```
   "styles": [
     "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
   ]
   ```

Comment: This is the proper angular way to do it!

Comment: ...and the proper way to do it when using Angular  for Apps (like with Cordova)

Comment: This works for me. Instead of using google api, I install material design.

Comment: +1 I like that this approach makes use of a library, but also good to note that the library doesn't seem to fully support all the icons listed in Googles official docs https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons

Comment: I left my laptop until the next day to finish the npm install for this library..

Comment: Note that the npm install will take a while to complete. Just be patient.

Comment: Instead of downloading the entire dev environment for icons, use `npm i material-design-icons-iconfont`.  Much quicker.

Answer (score 44):

In my case, there was a style applied that overrides font family. So, I added font family style explicitly like this:

```
.material-icons{
    font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

Comment: This was the answer for me! I just removed the font-family that was blocking it though instead of adding the !important

Comment: I had the same issue because of a brutal overriding I write to change all fonts of my app ! 
The good solution was the removal of this CSS class and its integration in the body class. It is not a very good idea to add more overriding...

Answer (score 35):

If using SASS you only need to add this line to your main `.scss` file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
```

---

If you prefer to avoid fetching icons from google you can also self-host the icons as described in [Material Icons Guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web):

> For those looking to self host the web font, some additional setup is
>   necessary. Host the icon font in a location, for example
>   https://example.com/material-icons.woff and add the following CSS
>   rule:
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'Material Icons';
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-weight: 400;
>   src: url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
>   src: local('Material Icons'),
>     local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
>     url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
>     url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
>     url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
> }
> ```
>
> In addition, the CSS rules for rendering the icon will need to be
>   declared to render the font properly. These rules are normally served
>   as part of the Google Web Font stylesheet, but will need to be
>   included manually in your projects when self-hosting the font:
>
> ```
> .material-icons {
>   font-family: 'Material Icons';
>   font-weight: normal;
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
>   display: inline-block;
>   line-height: 1;
>   text-transform: none;
>   letter-spacing: normal;
>   word-wrap: normal;
>   white-space: nowrap;
>   direction: ltr;
>
>   /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
>   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
>   /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
>   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
>
>   /* Support for Firefox. */
>   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
>
>   /* Support for IE. */
>   font-feature-settings: 'liga';
> }
> ```

Comment: Faced the issue when icon was not rendering and instead Close text was displaying. Appended the above import in my scss file and it started displaying the 'X' icon. Thanks :)

Comment: I have angular 9 project and after import material icon font file in .scss, still same issue, material icon is not visible, it is displaying test 'visibility_off' in .apk file created using cordova. but same is working fine in localhost:4200 So there any other solution of it?

Answer (score 13):

You must import **MatIconModule** and use the following url in index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 13):

- At first install angular material using -

  ```
  npm i @angular/material
  ```
- In **style.css** file just copy and paste -

  ```
    @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
  ```
- Then go to  **app.module.ts** follow the below instruction -

  ```
   import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

   imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          MatIconModule,
          ................
         ],
  ```
- In **app.component.html** file just copy and paste below code -

  ```
       <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
  ```
- And boom. It works for me. I hope, it will help you.

Comment: this is the latest working solution. Yet, css step is not necessary as I checked in index.html head, it is added automatically on installation

Answer (score 11):

The full solution can be :

**Step one**

You have to import `MatIconModule` in your project, in my project I import the necessary component in a separate file then I import it in the AppModule, you can use this or import them directly :

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MatIconModule, MatButtonModule], // note the imports 
    exports: [MatIconModule, MatButtonModule], // and the exports
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

**Step two**

Load the icon font in your `index.html` :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Step two would not be necessary because when I installed the module, that link is added automatically into my index.html.

In my case, it is the syntax using mat-icon in component.html:
NOT WORKING: <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>...... WORKING: <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>

Comment: I find like I'm trying do a "where's Waldo?", with the imports for Material modules. Of course, it's *obvious* now, that MatButtonToggleModule should be imported from '@angular/material/button-toggle', but it actually *isn't*. Folks at @angular/material just have ONE import that imports all material objects, and the end programmer can pick and choose which ones to use..

Answer (score 11):

First, please consider that you need to insert style into the project:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

If the problem didn't solved, I guess you are using another font with !important in your style, please try to add this css class in to style.css (or style.scss) which is the general/public CSS :

```
mat-icon{
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

refer to this answer: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5863#issuecomment-316307387

Comment: should be mat-icon instead of md-icon

Answer (score 4):

In my case the icons did not show up because I has screwed up my fonts by using !important. Taking that out caused the icons to appear.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the icon name I wrote wasn't associated to any icon.

You can check the correct names here:
https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Answer (score 4):

You can import **Material icons** in two ways. one is to import the icon in the main index.html page in your project.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

The other way is to import **Material icons** to the main CSS file as following you can see.

```
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
```

**My opinion is to add it to CSS file.**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not overriding the default `font-family: 'Material Icons';` with stronger CSS selector such as:

```
* :not(i){
    font-family: Nunito !important;
}
```

The above CSS example would change the font for `<mat-icon>` elements, and they will show text instead of icons.

Answer (score 2):

I realized no one spoke about installing hammerJs at first before importing it to your app. Well for people who have a similar issue you need to import hammerJs at first, you can use either NPM, Yarn or google CDN for the installation. This answer is for installation with either NPM or Yarn:

NPM

```
npm install --save hammerjs
```

Yarn

```
yarn add hammerjs
```

After installing, import it on your app's entry point (e.g. src/main.ts).

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

If you prefer to use Google CDN kindly visit the Angular material for more explanation https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: hammerjs (https://hammerjs.github.io/) adds touch gesture... it should not change anything about icons' angular module or style.
If it does it would be a border effect that I would not rely upon.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the issue of icons not displaying for me. I had followed the steps provided by Basavaraj Bhusani however still not working.

I found the issue was that in my scss, I had the `text-transform: uppercase` which was causing the icon to just display the content 'arrow_forward'. I had to change the `text-transform: none` on the icon specifically otherwise it would not render.

```
                .child-item-action {

                    text-transform: uppercase;

                    &:after {

                        font-family: 'Material Icons';
                        content: "arrow_forward";
                        text-transform: none;
                        -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have overwritten some existing Angular Material styling or any other styling that somehow affects the icon, it may cause an issue. Move the icon code outside of any styling and test.

For me it was   font-variant: small-caps;

So I just moved it to the child element. Below is part of Angular Material grid.

```
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="1" class='title customGlobalGrid'>
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</maticon>
    <span style="font-variant: small-caps;">{{item['title']}}</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong Icon Name** : Some Material Icon name is wrong.

**For example** : [Material Icon](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=filter_alt&style=baseline) provides *filter_alt* for

[image]

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label=" filter icon">filter_alt</mat-icon>
```

but it shows up

[image]

**Fix :**
we have to use ***filter_list_alt*** for  funnel type icon as

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="filter icon">filter_list_alt</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by going to the link directly (https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons) and copying the CSS (which is)

```
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v129/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Put this CSS into your site's main style file at the very top. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the correct documentation.

Version 13.3.9:

`<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>`

Version 14.1.0:

`<mat-icon fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the default icon class had been changed in `app.module.ts` by using `MatIconRegistry.setDefaultFontSetClass`, so my `<mat-icon>` was not getting the `material-icons` class applied to it. Read more about this function [here](https://v13.material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#font-icons-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentioned here. What worked for me was on my dev machine enable proxy server under LAN settings.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy stuff.
Tried all above solutions but the Home icon never appeared.
What worked is, changing the text inside `<mat-icon>` from **"Home"** (observe the capital *'H'* to **"home"** with small case *'h'* worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not working because I did not imported the Material module in app.modules.ts file.

I just added MatIconModule in the declaration of the parent module file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 15 FAIL.

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

My version of this was caused by the DuckDuckGo browser extension. Once I disabled it for my target site the icons started working again.

Answer (score 0):

add this code: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/iconfamily=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet"/>`

to: `index.html` file

Answer (score 0):

Just install the material-icons package

```bash
yarn add material-icons
or
npm install material-icons
```

then import the css in your styles.scss

```
@import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

to use just use the class

```html
<span class="material-icons">pie_chart</span>          <!-- Filled -->
<span class="material-icons-outlined">pie_chart</span> <!-- Outlined -->
<span class="material-icons-round">pie_chart</span>    <!-- Round -->
<span class="material-icons-sharp">pie_chart</span>    <!-- Sharp -->
<span class="material-icons-two-tone">pie_chart</span> <!-- Two Tone -->
```

the library repo link is [Material Icons](https://github.com/marella/material-icons#readme) by @marella

Answer (score -1):

**Create preview-head.html inside in .storybook folder and add this link**
[][1]

Answer (score -2):

```
**Add following code to your css**

 .material-icons {  
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```