# How to properly install Material in an Angular Single SPA application?

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I downloaded the [starting project](https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends) of Angular Single SPA and I would like to install and use Angular Material in all the different applications (app1, app2, navbar). I thought that, since the applications are independent, would have been sufficient to normally install the package in each of them as explained [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). However, in this way the components are loaded up and I can use them but the assets seem not. For example, if I try to display an icon with

```
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</mat-icon>
```

I only see this:

[image]

What am I missing here? Should I add something inside the `extra-webpack.config.js` file?

**EDIT.**

The following is the `app.module.ts` of the navbar project:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmptyRouteComponent } from './empty-route/empty-route.component';
import { PrimaryNavComponent } from './primary-nav/primary-nav.component';

import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmptyRouteComponent,
    PrimaryNavComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my package.json of the navbar project:

```
{
  "name": "navbar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run serve:single-spa",
    "build": "npm run build:single-spa",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:single-spa": "ng build --prod --deploy-url /dist/navbar --output-hashing none",
    "serve:single-spa": "ng serve --disable-host-check --port 4300 --host 0.0.0.0 --deploy-url http://localhost:4300/ --live-reload false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "single-spa": "^5.5.0",
    "single-spa-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code. Maybe on stackblitz?

Comment: It's exactly the code of the starting project but I installed via `ng add` the Angular Material in all applications and replaced the html in `primary-nav.component.html` with the Material Icon you see above. That's it.

Comment: You also need to import MatIconModule to your App Module and add it to the imports array of the app.module.ts file

Comment: @JordanStubblefield yes, I have done it already and still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add your `app.module.ts` (or other module where you want to use the icon)? Also do you get any errors in console and/or terminal? Possible even add the `package.json` file?

Comment: @RubenSzekér I have edited my question. No errors in the console nor in the terminal.

Comment: @Rexam does [this stackoverflow's post answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796212/angular-material-icons-not-working)

Basically adding the stylesheet `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @Rexam your `package.json`, HTML and `app.module.ts` are fine so that's not the issue, but then you would've gotten an issue aswell

Comment: @RubenSzekér that worked!! Many thanks! I'll mark the question as duplicate.