# How to display an icon (Angular material) Output not appearing after compiling

Tags: angular, windows, angular-material, angular-ui-router, mat-icon

I have added and imported things for using mat-icon but I'm not having any output even if my codes got no errors after compiling. Here's what I did (btw I've used routing for my component)
Angular-material version: 6.14.15
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd3xI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Beller    a summary: I just want to display an icon on my page but my page does not do so even if i have already imported some codes for mat-icon

Comment: if you share more details/code, someone will help you to solve this problem. (Pls code no pics)

Comment: try to serve project again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796321/2358409